# nlog settings for ASP .NET Core 2.1 site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm trying to setup nlog to log into 3 separate log files. I want Entity Framework stuff to go to one log file (db.log). I want application-related logging only to go to another log file (own.log). And finally I want everything else (Microsoft stuff) to go to yet another file (all.log)

This is what I have below, but I can't get logging to work based on my requirements. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="info" >

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>

    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" 
            fileName="all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web"
            fileName="own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${activityid}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="sqllogfile"
            fileName="db-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${date}|${activityid}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}" />

  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="sqllogfile" final="true" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

    <!-- Our log -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Please tell what works, and what doesn't work. Instead of it is almost not working.Good idea to configure `throwconfigexceptions="true"`. Have you checked NLog internal log?

Comment: I'm not getting desired result. With the posted configuration, I get Entity Framework logging in the separate file, but the same database logging also occurs in all.log file. And I don't get separate own.log file with application-only logging. Instead, I get everything in all.log file.

Comment: Move the logging-rule with `EntityFrameworkCore` to the top of the rules-section. Then it will not reach the `allFile` (Guess you should rename target since it is now not "allFile"). Can you give an example from the `allFile` that should have reached the `ownFile` ? (Want to see the logger-name used for logging)

Comment: Maybe you should read https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial and https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Comment: Moving database log to the top did the trick. I also moved the all file log to the bottom as the catch-all log. Now I'm getting exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Moving database log was the key. Also, after moving catch-all log to the bottom, I now get correct logging results.

Comment: If the "catch all" you have moved to the bottom is this `<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />`, then you should just remove it since it doesn't do anything then.